# Does Picasso support streaming of progressive jpeg?

Tags: picasso, fresco

Does Picasso support streaming of progressive `.jpeg`s or is [Fresco](http://arjunu.com/2015/05/progressive-jpegs-with-facebook-fresco/) the only option for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fresco is the only Android imaging library I am aware of that supports progressive loading of JPEG images.